# Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent. vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, csv

I'm working on something where I should export an information to a csv file, but when I try to download it in the line `Response.AddHeader(" content-disposition "attachment; filename = GridViewExport.csv")`

I get the error:

> Server can not append header after HTTP headers have been sent.

My gridview is inside og a update panel

```
Public Sub archivoGenerado()

    For Each RW As GridViewRow In Dgdatoo.Rows
        If CType(RW.Cells(10).FindControl("CheckBox2"), CheckBox).Checked = True Then
            'If CType(RW.Cells(10).FindControl("Radio"), RadioButton).Checked = True Then
            Dim estatus As [String] = CType(RW.Cells(8).FindControl("LabEs"), Label).Text
            Dim Centro As [String] = DirectCast(RW.Cells(1).FindControl("LabeCe"), Label).Text
            Dim almacen As [String] = DirectCast(RW.Cells(3).FindControl("LabeAl"), Label).Text
            Dim Dupla As [String] = DirectCast(RW.Cells(6).FindControl("LabeDu"), Label).Text

            Dim constr As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
            constr.ConnectionString = C.GetAppConfiguracion("Inventario", "ConnInventario")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Vw_RptInventarioSAP.IdMaterial as 'Barcode / Item-ID',Vw_RptInventarioSAP.MaterialNombre as'Description',S_AsignacionDuplas.Cantidad as 'Quantity',Vw_RptInventarioSAP.IdLote as 'Lote',S_AsignacionDuplas.IdCentro as 'Centro',S_AsignacionDuplas.IdAlamacen as 'Almacen',S_AsignacionDuplas.IdDupla as 'Dupla' from Vw_RptInventarioSAP inner join S_AsignacionDuplas on Vw_RptInventarioSAP.IdMaterial = S_AsignacionDuplas.IdMaterial where S_AsignacionDuplas.IdDupla = '" & Dupla & "' and IdCentro ='" & Centro & "' and IdAlmacen= '" & almacen & "'")
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.Connection = constr
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Using dt As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)

                        'Build the CSV file data as a Comma separated string.
                        Dim csv As New StringBuilder()
                        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                            csv.Append(dt.Columns(i).ColumnName + ",")
                        Next

                        csv.Append(Environment.NewLine)

                        For j As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                            For k As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                                csv.Append(dt.Rows(j)(k).ToString() + ",")

                            Next
                            csv.Append(Environment.NewLine)
                        Next
                        For Each RW2 As GridViewRow In Dgdatoo.Rows

                            Response.Clear()
                            Response.ClearContent()

                            Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
                            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=GridViewExport.csv")

                            Response.Write(csv.ToString())
                            Response.Flush()




                        Next


                        'Next

                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Else
            With lbError0
                .Visible = True
                .Text = "Selecionar inventario a descargar"
            End With
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add headers to a response anyway?

Comment: thats was the ia could make the csv file

Comment: if quit taht show me the error : JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.

Comment: Like the error says you cannot append additional headers when all the HTTP headers have been sent, that is, when the web browser has started downloading and displaying the page. If this method is always called after that point you'll have to find some other way to do it.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to send several `.scv` files in a single response. That is you do it for each row in a `GriView`.

Comment: I'm also getting this error. I'm serving up a single .pdf file, and ***it downloads the form successfully*** but I still get this error, which pops up in debugging right after the download file dialogue box pops up. If I catch the exception and do nothing with it, it works fine, but I can't help but think that this is asking for trouble.